# pyinstaller dynamic module additions

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have a python project, that can dynamically load other modules based on user inputs by main.  I have pyintaller building the exe fine along with all the required modules needed and this all works fine.  But I have a directory filled with algorithms, built written too in python, that can be dynamically loaded based on user action from the main exe.  How can OR can these files also be converted to binaries from the spec file.
I have a number of algorithms in 'share/smartsheetAlgo' that too need to be converted to binary files. Is there are way from the spec sheet, now they are included as py files

Here is my spec file

## -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

```
a = Analysis(['stecsmartsheet.py'],
             pathex=['/home/ed/smartsheet','/usr/local/lib/python3.8'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('./share/original_filenames.txt','share'),
                    ('./share/smartsheetAlgo/*.py','share/smartsheetAlgo'),
                    ('./share/projects/*.prj','share/projects'),
                    ('./share/icons/*.*','share/icons'),
                    ('./share/icons/actions/*.*','share/icons/actions'),
                    ('./share/icons/charts/*.*','share/icons/charts'),
                    ('./share/icons/status/*.*','share/icons/status'),
                    ('./share/libs/win32/*.*','.'),
                    ],
             hiddenimports=['VremAlgoinfo','parseline','statistics','pyqtgraph'],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts, 
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='smartsheet',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas, 
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='smartsheet')
```

Comment: Just to better understand the problem: why is it not okay for you to use the *.py files?

Comment: Some of the py files used as dynamic modules, not all but some, we don't want users to fiddle with. Some of the stuff will be used in am industrial situation and fiddling users can break things if modified.